# Using onEdit(e) in google sheets to automattically add a value to a specific cell

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, triggers

I want to use the onEdit function to automatically add a value to an empty cell, I can't get the onEdit function to work however. How do you correctly use onEdit?

This sheet is connected to a form, if that form adds data to the sheet, lets say column 5, I want it to add a value to the cell G5.

How can I find out which column has been edited?

Please point it out if these questions have been answered before, I could not find anything about this topic.

Comment: A form submissions is not an edit. You may want to use an installable onFormSubmit trigger.  See also: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable

Comment: onEdit  triggers only occur on user edit.